# Class-validator decorators on Typescript mixin classes

Tags: typescript, class-validator

In my project, I have a large object with many properties. Each property has it's own distinct validations that are performed on it using [class validator decorators](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator). Each property for the class is described as a mixin. However, I noticed that when applying mixins to the base class, only the mixin that was passed last has its decorators run for validation.

For example, we have:

```js
export class Property {
  public async validate (): Promise<string[]> {
    const result = await validate(this)
    return result
  }
}

export class Name extends Property {
  @IsDefined()
  @IsString()
  @Length(5, 255)
  name: string
}

export class Description extends Property {
  @IsDefined()
  @IsString()
  @Length(16, 1000)
  description: string
}
```

Each property, when unit tested, validates itself correctly.

When creating the class that inherits from the mixins, I am doing the following:

```js
/**
 * Applies the mixins to a class. Taken directly from the Typescript documentation.
 */
function applyMixins (derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) {
  baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
      Object.defineProperty(derivedCtor.prototype, name, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(baseCtor.prototype, name))
    })
  })
}

export class Foo {
  public async validate (): Promise<any> {
    const result = await validate(this)
    return result
  }
}

export interface Foo extends Name, Description { }
applyMixins(Foo, [Name, Description])
```

But, when creating an instance of `Foo` and calling `.validate` on the instance, we only get errors for Description.

Is there some different way to apply the mixins in order to get validations on all of the mixed in properties?

Comment: The reason od this behavior decorators add your class some internal properties as metadata. When you use them in mixin they get overwritten by the last one.

Comment: @Eldar Am I able to apply the mixins in some different way to avoid this? or is the entire approach not going to be able to work?

Comment: My comment was an assumption. Need to dig into source code to figure out a work around or a solution

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/tannerntannern/ts-mixer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because сlass-validator uses prototype to detect validation rules, and we need to copy the rules to the prototype of derived ctor.

We can do that like this:

```js
/**
 * Applies the mixins to a class, but with class validator constraints.
 */
function applyMixinsWithValidators (derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) {
  const metadata = getMetadataStorage() // from class-validator

  // Base typescript mixin implementation
  baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
      Object.defineProperty(derivedCtor.prototype, name, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(baseCtor.prototype, name))
    })
  })

  baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
    // Get validation constratints from the mixin
    const constraints = metadata.getTargetValidationMetadatas(baseCtor.prototype.constructor, '')

    for (const constraint of constraints) {
      // For each constraint on the mixin
      // Clone the constraint, replacing the target with the the derived constructor
      let clone = {
        ...constraint,
        target: derivedCtor.prototype.constructor
      }
      // Set the prototype of the clone to be a validation metadata object
      clone = Object.setPrototypeOf(clone, Object.getPrototypeOf(constraint))
      // Add the cloned constraint to class-validators metadata storage object
      metadata.addValidationMetadata(clone)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: This answer isn't working as is, but I'm working on tweaking it to see if i can get something similar working. Right now, the constraints array is always empty so nothing is really happening.

Comment: I think you need to play with `metadata.getTargetValidationMetadatas` and `metadata.addValidationMetadata`.

Comment: let me know how it went, I'll be able to dig deeper on weekend if it's needed.

Comment: its odd becaue right now,
```javascript
const c = metadata.getTargetValidatorConstraints(baseCtor)
console.log(c)
```
c is still an empty array. But based on the docs, it should return the constraints on the function baseCtor

Comment: for `getTargetValidationMetadatas` it requires a 2nd parameter of `targetSchema` but I'm, not sure what to provide as its a string

Comment: scratch that, was just able to make some progress with `const c = metadata.getTargetValidationMetadatas(baseCtor.prototype.constructor, '')`

Comment: aha, okay, then I think both places should be `prototype.constructor`, I've updated it.

Comment: got it working! will update the answer and accept it in a bit